# How to apply page-break AUTO to print a table (MAT TABLE) with lots of rows?

Tags: html, css, angular, mat-table, page-break

I have a dynamic table in my web page that sometimes contains lots of rows. I'm using `mat table` `(mat-table, ng-container, ..)`

The problem is it only shows one sheet and that enables up to 10 rows. I want to show the rest of the rows on a second sheet.
Put style `page-break` at the end of the table (mat-row) but only works the property: ALWAYS when set Property: AUTO doesn't work.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;let i = index;" 
style="page-break-after: always;">
</mat-row>
```

This way it makes a page break for each row, but it is not what I need. Do I need something else to make Property: AUTO work?

Comment: Hello @Dani Q, Did you find any solution ?